stripe connect api - hold fund until event
i am trying to build a project using stripe connect api for the buy/sell of good.
I chose the solution where my platform take an application fee and therefore the money goes to the seller directly while strip and my platform take a fee.
I would like however for the money to be given to the vendor only when the user confirm that they received the good. Is that something the API would allow? what would be the way to build this?
thanks
it is more of an investigation into options

you can use the separate charges and transfers flow to keep the funds in platform first, and only transfer them to the connected account when you think the time is appropriate.
